# D3, iterate over objects to create several pie charts within the same container

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a some data that I am using to create many charts.  I am using d3.nest to create a key so I can organize my charts by date.  Everything seems to be working except that I cannot get the pie function to iterate over the 2 sample objects that are being created.

Here is the code snippet:

```
var data1 = [
    {"date":"June2013", "type":"coal", "total":20, "color": "purple", "lat": 100, "long": 100},
    {"date":"June2013", "type":"wind", "total":30, "color": "blue", "lat": 100, "long": 100},
    {"date":"June2013", "type":"nuclear", "total":40, "color": "yellow", "lat": 100, "long": 100},
    {"date":"July2013", "type":"coal", "total":50, "color": "purple", "lat": 500, "long": 200},
    {"date":"July2013", "type":"wind", "total":60, "color": "blue", "lat": 500, "long": 200},
    {"date":"July2013", "type":"nuclear", "total":70, "color": "yellow", "lat": 500, "long": 200}
];

  var energyT = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { 
      return d.date; 
  })
  .entries(data1); 

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(40)
        .outerRadius(50);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function (d){
            return d.total;
        });
        //console.log("what is the length of energyT: " + energyT.length)
        //printout:  what is the length of energyT: 2
        //it knows there are 2 objects
var arcs = svg.selectAll("arc")
        //.data(pie(energyT[0].values))
        .data(function (d, i){
            //console.log("what is i: " + JSON.stringify(energyT[i].values))
            //printout:  what is i: [{"date":"June2013","type":"coal","total":20,"color":"purple","lat":100,"long":100},...
            //it correctly passes the values of the first object 
            //but it doesn't iterate to the next
            return pie(energyT[i].values);
        })
        .enter()
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", function(d){
            return "translate(" + d.data.lat+ "," + d.data.long + ")"
        });

      arcs.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
            console.log("what is d in color " + JSON.stringify(d.data.color))
                return d.data.color;
    });
});
```

Also, if I pass it an exact index (.data(pie(energyT[0].values)) it will draw that chart.  I don't understand how to iterated over both objects.  Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to read that there were two objects.  I needed to also pass energyT in the function like so:

```
.data(energyT, function (d, i){
            return pie(energyT[i].values);
        })
```

So that part is solved, now I cannot get it to draw any arcs because there is an invalid path value.  It's strange because I can pass data without using the d3.nest to create the key value but as soon as I add the key in even if the values appear to being passed correctly it no longer works.

My initial problem has been solved.